# Usar RegEx para substituir texto

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso exibir um texto e substituir algumas palavras por um campo do tipo `input`. A ideia é que ele preencha neste `input` a palavra que foi escondida. É como se fosse um jogo de adivinhação.

Então vamos supor que eu tenha o seguinte texto:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

Eu quero esconder a palavra "ipsum" deste texto, fazendo com que um campo `input` apareça no lugar dela.

Eu pensei em marcar a palavra usando os sinais `<< >>`, desta forma eu poderia usar regex para encontrar estes caracteres, e depois fazer a substituição deste conteúdo com JQuery. Eu acho que o site https://regexr.com/ faz exatamente isso.

O problema é que eu não faço ideia de que tipo de expressão regular utilizar para fazer isso. Na verdade, eu nem sei se isso é possível.

Eu nem sequer tenho um código aproximado disso porque nunca usei expressões regulares. A única coisa que eu tenho até agora é isso:

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

var search = "lorem";

var match = search.split(" ").every(function (word) {
    var regex = new RegExp(word, "i");
    return regex.test(text);
});

if (match) {
    alert("String '" + search + "' Encontrada.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A princípio, você poderia simplesmente criar o HTML com o texto e o `input`, mas se a ideia é que seja dinâmico, uma alternativa seria:

```js
var p = document.querySelector('#texto');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var text = p.innerText; // pega o texto
    var palavra = 'ipsum'; // palavra a ser substituída
    // procura pela palavra
    var regex = new RegExp(`\\b${palavra}\\b`);
    var match = regex.exec(text);
    if (match) { // se encontrou
        p.innerHTML = ''; // limpa o elemento

        // cria textnodes com os trechos antes e depois da palavra, e também o input
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.slice(0, match.index))); // texto antes da palavra

        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.size = palavra.length;
        p.appendChild(input);

        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.slice(match.index + palavra.length))); // texto depois da palavra
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <p id="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</form>
```

Ou seja, a regex busca pela palavra, tomando o cuidado de usar o atalho `\b` (o [*word boundary*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052)), para evitar que pegue partes de uma palavra (por exemplo, se a frase for "Cuidado com o dado", a palavra for "dado" e a regex não usasse `\b`, o "dado" da palavra "Cuidado" seria encontrado e substituído; já usando `\b` eu garanto que a regex pega a palavra "dado" corretamente). O mesmo problema ocorreria se eu usasse `text.indexOf(palavra)`, por exemplo (que seria uma solução sem regex, se não tivesse esse problema de pegar partes de uma palavra).

Vale lembrar também que só estou pegando a primeira ocorrência (se a palavra ocorrer mais de uma vez, só vai pegar a primeira).

Depois, eu pego o texto do parágrafo (coloquei o texto em um elemento para ficar mais fácil encontrá-lo e manipulá-lo), e como o `match` tem a posição em que a palavra está, eu consigo pegar os trechos antes e depois da palavra. Aí é só criar *text nodes* com esses textos, além do próprio `input`, e inserir tudo no elemento que originalmente tinha o texto completo.

E sobre criar a `RegExp` usando uma palavra qualquer, vale [esta leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458289/112052).