# Qual o regex para todas as palavras inteiras e com acento?

Tags: javascript, regex, acentuação

A partir de uma variável `var palavra = 'nascer'` (por exemplo) qual a expressão regular que pega **todas** as palavras **inteiras** de um texto? Incluindo as palavras que possuem acento no início ou no final.

Considerações:

- Palavra **não é** substring - isso significa que `"nasceram".includes("nascer")` retorna `true`; pra mim não funciona pois eu considero palavras e não substrings
- estou tendo cuidado em não considerar espaços em branco e pontuação (antes e depois) porque a variavel `palavra` só terá a 'palavra' de fato: nada antes, nada depois.
- eu usei boundaries que é bem decente, mas o boundaries não pega acento

Eu fiz isso:

```js
var palavra = 'nascer'

// a regex que pega todas as palavras 'nascer'
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${palavra}\\b`, 'g');
```

Com esse 'boundaries' e o 'global'. Ele funciona. Pega todas as palavras, e inteiras, sem derivadas como 'nasceram' ou 'nascerão'.

Mas o boundaries não aceita acento, portanto ele não pega quando a variável começa ou termina com acento:

```js
var palavra = 'água'
//ou
var palavra = 'café'
```

Nos casos acima ele não resolve.

Como melhorar esse regex para selecionar (a partir da variável) palavras inteiras, inclusive com acento no início ou final?

Tentei alguma coisa com `^` e o `$` mas não rolou:

```js
/^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$/
//ou isso
/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i
```

Não sei como colocar uma variável como critério de seleção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No JavaScript o [atalho `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) só considera os caracteres ASCII, então caracteres acentuados não são levados em consideração.

Uma alternativa é simular seu comportamento usando [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) juntamente com [*Unicode Property Escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`(?<!\\p{L})${palavra}(?!\\p{L})`, 'ug');
```

Primeiro temos um *lookbehind negativo*: o trecho dentro de `(?<! )`) que indica que antes da palavra não tem uma letra (sendo que `\p{L}` é qualquer letra definida pelo Unicode, o que inclui inúmeros alfabetos diferentes, como o japonês, árabe, etc, e também caracteres acentuados).

E no fim temos um *lookahead negativo*: o trecho dentro de `(?! )`, que indica que depois da palavra não tem uma letra.

Ou seja, é como se fosse a "versão Unicode" do `\b` (bem simplificada, porque na verdade [o atalho `\b` é um pouco mais complicado que isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052)).

Note que, para que o `\p` funcione, [precisa colocar a *flag* `u`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052).

Testando:

```js
function testar(palavra, frase) {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(?<!\\p{L})${palavra}(?!\\p{L})`, 'ug');
    // troca a palavra por X, para vermos se pegou as ocorrências corretas
    console.log(frase.replace(regex, 'X'));
}

testar('água', 'tem água nas águas, deságua'); // tem X nas águas, deságua
testar('café', 'toma café mas não nescafé, cafés, café'); // toma X mas não nescafé, cafés, X
```

---

Por fim, fica a dica de tomar alguns cuidados ao se criar uma regex cujo valor é uma variável qualquer: [Criar expressões regulares com um padrão dinâmico é problemático? Se sim, há como evitar o problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458289/112052)

---

E só para constar, sobre essa regex que você tentou:

```
/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i
```

Isso não funciona porque ela significa o seguinte:

- os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` indicam o início e fim da string
- depois tem a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]`, que pega letras com e sem acento e espaço
- e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "um ou mais"
- e a *flag* `i` faz com que considere maiúsculas e minúsculas

Portanto, esta regex pega uma ou mais ocorrências de letras (com e sem acento) e espaços, do início ao fim da string. O que quer dizer que ela só dá *match* se a string inteira tiver somente esses caracteres. Basta que tenha algum diferente (como um sinal de pontuação, por exemplo) que ela já não encontra nenhum *match*. Ou seja, algo bem diferente do que você precisa.

Comment: HUm, perfeito. Alguma ideia sobre lidar com o case sensitive? por exemplo `testar('água', 'Água nas águas, deságua');` ele também troca 'Água' por X ? Tentei a opção 'ugi' mas não pegou.

Comment: @LukeNegreiros A flag `i` deveria funcionar: https://ideone.com/ZOU3TZ - não sei se é uma daquelas coisas que variam conforme o browser, pois hoje em dia o suporte a Unicode já está bem razoável, mas não duvidaria...

Comment: a minha implementação está errada. Olhe isso: https://jsfiddle.net/apw1ruy2/ é um programinha para marcar palavras repetidas dentro de uma frase, com mais de três letras. E na função `marcar_palavra_repetida()` lá embaixo, eu crio uma `fraseHTML` e uso a variavel 'palavra' do parâmetro para construir essa string, por isso ele nunca iria marcar duas palavras iguais ignorando o case sensitive (repare na segunda linha, a palavra 'Advinha' com 'advinha' na mesma frase - gostaria que marcasse também).

Comment: @LukeNegreiros O problema do "Advinha" é que `indexOf` não é case insensitive: https://jsfiddle.net/4yk6xf83/1/