# Usar variável como parâmetro do RegExp no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, variáveis

Bom dia,

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação onde digito uma string e então é exibido todos os nomes que iniciam com a string que eu digitei.

O problema é que essa string é armazenada em uma variável.
A dificuldade que tenho está em criar uma expressão regular que aceita variável como parâmetro.

Pesquisei bastante sobre o assunto, mas encontrei apenas exemplos usando strings (ao invés de usar variáveis como parâmetro).
Segue o trecho do código da aplicação

```js
let listaNome = ['João Nascimento Junior', 'Herculina Costa', 'Junior Silva', 'Maria Julian', 'Augusto Junior', 'Marcus Caio', 'Pedro Junior', 'Jacun Halmth', 'Junny Almeida']

let pesquisaNome = 'Jun'
      
if (listaNome.match(/^pesquisaNome/)){ //Tentativa de usar expressão regular com variavel
  console.log('Encontrei exatamente os nomes que iniciam com a string que eu digitei')
}
```

No if, estou tentando criar uma expressão regular que aceita variável como parâmetro e que filtre todos os nomes que iniciam com o valor da variável (mas até agora sem sucesso).

Comment: Recomendo que use Regex apenas aonde exigir complexidade na busca, para casos simples (parece ser o da pergunta) prefira usar os métodos [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), exemplo: `if (variavel.indexOf(palavra) === 0)` (o zero é a posição que indica que a palavra deve *casar* na variável que fará a busca) ou o método [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), exemplo: `if (variavel.startsWith(palavra))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do jeito que fez não irá funcionar, você cometeu alguns erros:

1. Usar método de regex em [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

   Quando vc faz isso `listaNome.match(...` está incorreto, pq **`listanome`** é um **array**, e você está tentando utilizar o método **`match`** nele.
2. Utilizar [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) em uma estrutura if

   O método **match** retorna uma novo array com os resultados correspondentes à expressão regular ou `null`, ou seja, o seu `if` seria basicamente isso **`if([...])`** ou **`if(null)`**.

Pode fazer o que deseja percorrendo o array e utilizando o método [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), que retorna um booleano para ver se os nomes contidos no array passam:

```js
let listaNome = ['João Nascimento Junior', 'Herculina Costa', 'Junior Silva', 'Maria Julian', 'Augusto Junior', 'Marcus Caio', 'Pedro Junior', 'Jacun Halmth', 'Junny Almeida'];

let regex = /^Jun/;

for (let i = 0; i < listaNome.length; i++) {
  console.log(regex.test(listaNome[i]));
}
```

Para poder ver os nomes que passaram pelo teste, pode fazer como no código abaixo:

```js
let listaNome = ['João Nascimento Junior', 'Herculina Costa', 'Junior Silva', 'Maria Julian', 'Augusto Junior', 'Marcus Caio', 'Pedro Junior', 'Jacun Halmth', 'Junny Almeida'];

let regex = /^Jun/;

for (let i = 0; i < listaNome.length; i++) {
  let result = regex.test(listaNome[i]);

  if (result) {      // ou if (regex.test(listaNome[i]))
    console.log(`Encontrei exatamente os nomes que iniciam com a string que eu digitei: ${listaNome[i]}`);
  }
}
```

Agora para pegar valores dinâmicos pode utilizar o construtor [RegExp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
let listaNome = ['João Nascimento Junior', 'Herculina Costa', 'Junior Silva', 'Maria Julian', 'Augusto Junior', 'Marcus Caio', 'Pedro Junior', 'Jacun Halmth', 'Junny Almeida'];
let val = 'Mar';
let regex = new RegExp('^' + val);

for (let i = 0; i < listaNome.length; i++) {
  let result = regex.test(listaNome[i]);

  if (result) { // ou if (regex.test(listaNome[i]))
    console.log(`Encontrei exatamente os nomes que iniciam com a string que eu digitei: ${listaNome[i]}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas no lugar da let regex, ao invês de usa a string 'Jun', eu gostaria de usar uma variavel que possui o valor 'Jun', pois o valor da variavel irá mudar dinamicamente conforme o usuario decidir. Como posso fazer essa tratativa?

Comment: @CássiodaCostaeSilva editei a resposta : )

Comment: Top demais!!! Muito obrigado :D

Comment: @CássiodaCostaeSilva Só um detalhe, quando for criar regex com padrões dinâmicos (ou seja, cujos valores serão variáveis e/ou nem sempre vc controla a origem, etc), tem alguns cuidados a serem tomados - ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458289/112052). Inclusive, **nesse caso específico**, como a ideia é só ver se a string começa com algo, poderia ser apenas `if (listaNome[i].startsWith(val))`, por exemplo

Comment: @hkotsubo muito interessante o seu comentário. É uma lógica que exige menos código e resulta a mesma coisa. Obrigado pela contribuição ^^