# Transformar texto em RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Existe uma forma de transformar um texto qualquer que contém um regex válido em um regex?

Exemplo simples, poderia ser qualquer outro RegExp válido:

```
let regex = '/ola/g'
let texto = 'ola mundo, ola mundo!'
console.log(texto.replace(new RegExp(regex), 'olá')) // ola mundo, ola mundo!
```

Veja que mesmo tendo um regex como um texto, e passando para o construtor `new RegExp(regex)` não faz a substituição, o resultado esperado deveria ser:

```
// olá mundo, olá mundo!
```

Comment: Como já comentado abaixo, ao aceitar qualquer texto como regex, tem que tomar alguns cuidados: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458289/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo Sim, mas no texto eu especifico que sempre vai ser um regex válido.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Fiz algumas alterações no texto, veja se consegue entender.

Comment: Leia o link que indiquei, principalmente a seção "*ReDoS e os perigos de criar regex com entradas de usuário*" - veja que o problema ocorre com uma regex válida

Answer (score 4):

A estrutura deve ser `new RegExp(pattern, flags)`, a parte do pattern é o que está entre `/.../` e as flags/modificadores são os que estão após a última `/`, então basta separar a string e ajustar corretamente conforme o método funciona, um exemplo simples aplicável:

```js
var input = '/olá/g';

// Verifica aonde aonde o pattern termina
var endPos = input.lastIndexOf('/');

// Remove o primeiro caractere e remove a parte do modificador
var pattern = input.substring(1, endPos);

// Pega o modificador após o pattern
var flags = input.substring(endPos + 1);

console.log('pattern:', pattern, 'flags:', flags);

// Cria uma regex
var re = new RegExp(pattern, flags);

// Testa
console.log(re.test('olá'));
console.log(re.test('hello'));
```

Note que permitir entrada do usuário para gerar expressões regulares podem causar problemas, como ReDos.

---

### Evitando Negação de Serviço de Expressão Regular (ReDoS)

Conforme explicado em [Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) e [Preventing Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/redos.html), se o servidor aceitar regexs do usuário, o usuário poderá facilmente fornecer uma expressão que leve a um *retrocesso catastrófico*.

Se o servidor aceitar expressões enviadas pelos usuários, eles poderão fornecer entradas que acionam *retrocesso catastrófico* em *expressões regulares* usados pelo servidor, se esses *expressões regulares* estiverem predispostos a *retrocesso catastrófico* o servidor fica suscetível à negação de serviço de expressão regular (ReDoS). Por exemplo, se um número elevado de usuários (ou um ator disfarçado de muitos usuários) fornece *expressões regulares* maliciosos e/ou sujeitos para correspondência, o servidor gasta quase todos os seus ciclos de CPU tentando corresponder a esses *expressões regulares*.

A única defesa real é usar um mecanismo de regex direcionado a texto. Esses motores não retrocedem. Seu desempenho depende do comprimento da string enviada pelo usuário, não da complexidade da expressão regular. Mas eles também não suportam recursos como backreferences que dependem de backtracking e que muitos usuários esperam.

Se seu aplicativo usa um mecanismo de retrocesso com *expressões regulares* fornecidas pelo usuário, você só pode atenuar as consequências do *retrocesso catastrófico* e você realmente precisa fazer isso. É muito fácil para pessoas com habilidades limitadas de regex criar acidentalmente um que degenere em *retrocesso catastrófico*.

Você precisará usar um mecanismo regex que aborte a tentativa de correspondência quando ocorrer um *retrocesso catastrófico*, em vez de executar até que o script trave ou o sistema operacional o elimine.

O mecanismo PCRE permite definir limites de recursão. Quanto mais baixos seus limites, melhor a proteção contra ReDoS, mas maior o risco de abortar *expressões regulares* legítimos que encontrariam uma correspondência válida com um pouco mais de tempo. Limites baixos de recursão podem impedir correspondências longas de regex. Tempos limite baixos podem abortar pesquisas em arquivos grandes muito cedo.

Linguagens/configurações para poder limitar o tempo:

- Ruby: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/04/03/ruby-3-2-0-preview1-released/
- PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php
- .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.-ctor#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-ctor(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-system-timespan)